# Pass data from a c++ program to a python program on linux

Tags: python, c++, linux

I have a c++ program that returns a value(the value changes constantly) and I would like to make a python program that takes the value that the c++ program returned and use it. 
I would like to ask if there is any way to perform this task or anything at all that can help me in achieving this.
I want the two programs to be able to run simultaneously.

Ok lets assume the c++ program is the code below:

```
int main() {
    int x = 1;
    while(1){
        fprintf(stdout,"%d\n", x);
        x++;
}
return 0;
```

}

How can I make a python program that takes the variable **x**  as its input each time it cahnges.

Comment: How does it return the value? Does it write it to `stdout` and then terminate? Do you control this C++ program? Is it the sort of thing you could convert to a dynamic library and load it into python with a foreign function library like ctypes or by writing a python c extension?

Comment: Tell us more about how you want them to run. Does one call the other? You could potentially setup a queue (zeromq comes to mind), or share an intermediate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *pipe* to forward your C++ program's **stdout** to your Python program's **stdin**:

```
#!/bin/bash
./my_cpp_program.x | ./my_python_program.py
```